# Run If Not after another If Not scenario

Tags: excel, vba

In my script After a Validation Item is Selected the code then selects the next cell and opens the validation list, what I am trying to accomplish is after that selection to then select the cell in the next column and then open that validation list to make a selection. I cannot seem to allow the one script to run after the other. The top snippet is where I am trying to implement the second If Not to run after the first If Not. The bottom snippet is the entire script.

```js
If TheSize = "" Then
     MsgBox "Now pick the size for your " & vbNewLine & TheItem, , "Apparel Selection" & " (Item# " & TheId & ")"
     Target.Offset(, 2).Select
     Target.Offset(, 2).Application.SendKeys "%{UP}"
End If
If TheColor = "" Then
    MsgBox "Now pick the Color for your " & vbNewLine & TheItem, , "Apparel Selection" & " (Item# " & TheId & ")"
    Target.Offset(, 3).Select
    Target.Offset(, 3).Application.SendKeys "%{UP}"
End If
```

```html
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A3")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("B3:B3").ClearContents
        Range("C3:C6").ClearContents
        Range("D3:D6").ClearContents
        Range("E3:E6").ClearContents
        Range("F3:F6").ClearContents
    End If
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1).Value = "" Then
            TheItem = Target.Value
            TheSize = Target.Offset(, 2).Value
            TheColor = Target.Offset(, 3).Value
            TheId = Target.Offset(, 4).Value
            If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C3:C6")) Is Nothing Then
                ItemVal = InputBox("How many of the " & (TheItem) & "'s Do you want?", "Apparel Selection" & " (Item# " & TheId & ")")
                Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1).Value = ItemVal
                If TheSize = "" Then
                    MsgBox "Now pick the size for your " & vbNewLine & TheItem, , "Apparel Selection" & " (Item# " & TheId & ")"
                    Target.Offset(, 2).Select
                    Target.Offset(, 2).Application.SendKeys "%{UP}"
                End If
                If TheColor = "" Then
                    MsgBox "Now pick the Color for your " & vbNewLine & TheItem, , "Apparel Selection" & " (Item# " & TheId & ")"
                    Target.Offset(, 3).Select
                    Target.Offset(, 3).Application.SendKeys "%{UP}"
                End If
                If ItemVal = "" Then
                    MsgBox "Pick The Item You Really Really Want", , "Canceled!"
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    Target.ClearContents
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
   
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C3:C6" & Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = vbNullString Then
            Range("D" & Target.Row) = vbNullString
            Range("E" & Target.Row) = vbNullString
            Range("F" & Target.Row) = vbNullString
        End If
    End If
exitHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Right now it is displaying the first message box to pick the size and then going immediately to the second message box to pick color and opening that drop down box,  I need to wait until the first drop down box selection has been made.

Comment: As it is, there's nothing stopping the script from running after opening the drop down box, so it will just keep going. Not sure what the best workaround would be, but one option is having the number choice in a custom userform with a list or combo box.

Comment: the sizes in the validation list are dependant upon the apparel item selected. For this sheet I need it to open the cell containing the size validation list items then after one is selected to open the cell containing the color validation choices.

Comment: Still, shouldn't be a problem to move the boxes to a userform.

Comment: How would a userform accomplish this?

Comment: Since I don't know exactly how you populate the drop downs right now, it's hard to make a specific example. But basically, instead of selecting and opening the validation list, you show the userform and add the relevant items to the combobox based on the choice made. Then you get the value chosen and put it back in your sheet, and hide the userform.  As for tips on how to code it, the first few results on a search should tell you most things needed. Like this : https://analysistabs.com/vba-code/excel-userform/combobox/ or this: https://www.contextures.com/xlUserForm02.html